# Obtain specific data from Google Firestore using Rest API calls (HTTP-GET)

Tags: rest, firebase, api, google-api, google-cloud-firestore

## Problem

**I want to retrieve specific data from Google Firestore.**

**It's only possible to get all of the 'Fields' data. But no specific data within fields**

*Example of the GET-Request:*

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?key=[My_API_KEY]&fields=fields
```

As you can see, It is possible to obtain all the items in the object 'Fields'. But it is not possible to get any further into detail to obtain more specific data (test, message, nodeID, ...)

## Tryouts

I have already tried:

- fields=fields/test
- fields=fields.test
- fields=fields(test)
- fields=fields/test/integerValue
- ...

## Expected Results

I want to obtain specific data like the String / integer value of my objects in 'Fields'.

*This example should return the integerValue with 30*

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?key=[My_API_KEY]&fields=fields/test
```

*This example should return 30*

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?key=[My_API_KEY]&fields=fields/test/integerValue
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

While browsing the web, I came across **Google Api Explorer**:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/

When trying out some possibilities, I came across this:

[https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?mask.fieldPaths=nodeID&fields=fields&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?mask.fieldPaths=nodeID&fields=fields&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

This gives me the right information

but I still need a more detailed form of this answer like only the **'EduBox-1234567'**

Comment: Have you found out how the return only **EduBox-1234567**?

Answer (score 1):

The way to retrieve a specific field is to use `mask.fieldPaths`. For example the following GET method:

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes/EduBox-1234567?key=[My_API_KEY]&fields=fields&mask.fieldPaths=nodeID

is going do return:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "nodeID": {
      "stringValue": "EduBox-1234567"
    }
 }
```

Documentation references [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/get#query-parameters) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore.projects.databases.documents.get/m/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.get).

Comment: This is just what OP have done and doesn't answer how to obtain only `EduBox-1234567` as the answer of the query.